# Figure caption - label font

Tags: fonts, captions, bold, small-caps

For my thesis i want a label caption:

- that has the sc font
- and its should be bold

Consider the following minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}% Required for customising the captions
\captionsetup{justification=justified,
   format=plain,font=small,labelfont=sc,margin=50pt}
   
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[th]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a Test Test. }
\label{}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The caption of this figure has the correct label font sc

[image]

If i now add

```
labelfont = bf
```

to the caption set up i only get the bold font

[image]

Is there way to get both (sc + bold)?

Comment: Then you will need a font that supports bold face small caps. Not many fonts do.

Comment: Times Roman fonts generally provide a bold/smallcap combination. Do ask yourself, though, what you're trying to achieve by using two separate forms of typographic emphasis: bolding and smallcaps. Too much typographic emphasis is about as welcome as being shouted at. Might your readers possibly dislike getting the impression that you're shouting at them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have re-discovered, Computer Modern -- the default font that's used if no other choice is made -- does *not* feature a smallcaps/bold combination of font attributes.

One font family that does provide a smallcaps/bold font attribute combination -- as well as smallcaps/italics and (gasp) smallcaps/bold/italic -- is Times Roman. You could load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages to get a contemporaneous interpretation of text and math Times Roman fonts. See "Figure 5" below for the result.

Do ask yourself, though, whether it's productive to employ two types of typographic emphasis -- bold and smallcaps -- together. Combining two types of emphasis can quickly come across as needless shouting, which is generally resented.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{figure}{-1}
\begin{figure}[th]
\caption{This is a simple test. }

\medskip

\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
\caption{This is a simple test. }

\captionsetup{labelfont={sc}}
\caption{This is a simple test. }

\captionsetup{labelfont={it}}
\caption{This is a simple test. }

\medskip

\captionsetup{labelfont={bf,it}}
\caption{This is a simple test. }

\captionsetup{labelfont={sc,bf}}
\caption{This is a simple test. }

\captionsetup{labelfont={sc,it}}
\caption{This is a simple test. }

\medskip

\captionsetup{labelfont={sc,bf,it}}
\caption{This is a simple test. }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```